# I would like hide other menu items when a menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to figure out how to hide other submenu items with a menu is clicked. Right now, when both menus are clicked they both show, which i do not want.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        alwaysOpen: false
    });

    function collapseAll() {
        $("#accordion")
            .filter(":has(.ui-state-active)")
            .accordion("activate", -1);
        $(".ui-accordion-header").blur();

    }
});
```

```
 <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="accordion">
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="about" runat="server" href="#" text="testing" />
            <div class="sub accordion">
                <ul>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="aboutTraci" runat="server" NavigateUrl="traci.aspx" Text="Traci" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="aboutTheBegan" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="How It All Began" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="aboutDesigners" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Designers" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="aboutPlaygroup" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Playgroup" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="aboutPlayground" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Playground" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="aboutTestimonials" runat="server" NavigateUrl="testimonials.aspx" Text="Testimonials" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="accordion">
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" href="#" Text="testing" />
            <div class="sub accordion">
                <ul>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="traci.aspx" Text="Traci" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="How It All Began" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Designers" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Playgroup" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Playground" /></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" NavigateUrl="testimonials.aspx" Text="Testimonials" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to hide other menu items when one is clicked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide other menu items when one is clicked you have to structure your html in a way that accordion api can make sense of it by adding headers like so: [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/dsj74/)

```
<ul class="accordion">
        <li>
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <ul class="accordion">
                <li>
                    <h4> Link 1</h4><p>content</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4> Link 2</h4><p>content</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4> Link 3</h4><p>content</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <ul class="accordion">
                <li>
                    <h4> Link 1</h4><p>content</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4> Link 2</h4><p>content</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4> Link 3</h4><p>content</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```